# Website Time to First Byte 60 sec

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, woocommerce, cloudflare

Dynamic content of my [website](https://nutikell.com/korv) has 60 second Time to First Byte. Static content for example [homepage](https://nutikell.com) has the same problem but as I am currently reloading most of my pages every 10 minutes it keeps the site loading normally for visitors - I use Cloudflare and W3 Total Cache. From admin side everything loads normally. I have disabled all plugins 1 by 1 - nothing changes except when disabling Woocommerce blank pages will be loaded quickly. I think that the problem might be in my theme code but unfortunately theme support could not figure out the problem (switching to some other theme makes the site run fast). There was no theme, plugin, code etc. change before the problem occurred. I really hope someone could give any advice regarding this problem.

Comment: (added image of the loading - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLY8u.png)

Comment: You may have to check your backend code. This doesn't look like anything related to front end assets.

Comment: @karthick Yes, I believe so too but I lack of experience in troubleshooting..perhaps you could give more specific directions?